# How to alter a column using entity framework when the database is set for replication

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

We have a database that has tables set for replication. The application we have written accesses the database via Entity Framework. EF was used as code first to generate the database. We need to change the column width of a couple of the columns in a table that is replicated. When we attempted to deploy the application we received a sql connection error, but what it ended up being is the fact that you cannot alter a table's columns without first turning off replication.

Is there a way to have EF detect replication and turn it off, make the changes and then turn it back on?

Comment: Your question is unclear because it is most definitely possible to change a table that's being replicated (as long as you update it at the publication database, of course, not the subscriber). By default, replication will propagate DDL changes. What's the exact error you get?

Comment: Is it possible to change the table on the publisher without turning off replication?

Comment: Yes. Changes to the table structure will be replicated to the subscribers (unless the publication has been specifically configured not to do that). You should never change replicated tables on the subscribers directly, because this may collide with future changes on the publisher and would require a reinitialization.

Comment: Note that I'm not considering Entity Framework in all this, as I have no experience using that on replicated tables -- all I know is that a plain old `ALTER TABLE` can definitely be replicated. EF may have its own restrictions.